# Calculating azimuth and elevation angles from direction cosines

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates, python

I've been scratching my head on this one for a while, I'm not very well versed in this subject area. Hopefully someone more mathematically gifted than I can assist in  explaining why this code is not working as intended. The expected outcome is to be able to input vector `i, j, k`, calculate the `direction cosines`, transform the cartesian components `x, y, z` to the spherical components `r, theta, phi`, and have it output the calculated elevation and azimuth. For all the code examples below, I am running it in `Python` with `NumPy` and have omitted other portions of the code for brevity.

**The rundown**

These lines take an input of three variables `i, j, k` . These variables are transformed into direction cosines via

```
magnitude  = np.sqrt(i**2 + j**2 + k**2)
x = i / magnitude
y = j / magnitude
z = k / magnitude
```

[image: Direction Cosines]

These a transformed from cartesian coordinates to spherical via (In the program I’ve flipped theta to get the angles in the correct axis)

```
r = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)
theta = np.arctan2(z, np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2))
phi = np.arctan2(y, x)
```

[image: Cartesian to Spherical]

Finally, `theta` and `phi` are converted from radians to degrees and output

```
elevation = np.degrees(theta)
azimuth = np.degrees(phi)
```

**A few observations**

Azimuth output works entirely as expected.

```
IN: i=1.0, j=0.0, k=0.0
OUT: el=0.0, az=0.0

IN: i=0.7071067811865476, j=0.7071067811865475, k=0.0
OUT: el=0.0, az=44.99999999999999
```

Elevation output is very close when angle is near 0 or 180 degrees, however error is significant at higher values (this applies for moving away from 0 degrees and 180 degrees).

```
IN: i=1.0, j=0.0, k=0.17364817766693033
OUT: el=9.851076116583906, az: 0.0 (Expected 10 degrees)

IN: i=1.0, j=0.0, k=0.766044443118978
OUT: el=37.453719557105146, az: 0.0 (Expected 50 degrees)
```

I'm assuming I must have made an error in the cartesian to spherical calculations and would greatly appreciate a fresh set of eyes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the coordinates
\begin{align}
 i&=1.0,\\ j&=0.0,\\ k&=0.17364817766693033,
\end{align}

consider the triangle with vertices
$(0,0,0),$ $(1,0,0),$ $(1,0,0.17364817766693033)$.
This is a right triangle with right angle at $(1,0,0).$
The other two vertices are the origin and your chosen point $(i,j,k).$

In this triangle, the leg opposite the origin has length $0.17364817766693033$ and the leg adjacent to the origin has length $1,$ so the ratio of those two legs,
$0.17364817766693033/1 = 0.17364817766693033,$
is the tangent of the angle at the origin. That angle is
$\arctan(0.17364817766693033) \approx 0.17193371309896594$ (in radians),
which is approximately $9.8510761165839062$ degrees.
Your program is giving the correct output.

You may have been thinking that by setting $k$ to the sine of $10$ degrees you should get a $10$ degree elevation. But the sine is the ratio of the opposite side of the triangle to the **hypotenuse**, that is, the ratio of $k$ to the magnitude $\sqrt{i^2+j^2+k^2}$. If you want to use $k=0.17364817766693033$ to get an elevation of $10$ degrees you need to ensure that $\sqrt{i^2+j^2+k^2} = 1,$
**not** that $i = 1.$
You can do this by setting $i$ to the cosine of $10$ degrees,
or you can set $i$ to $1$ but set $k$ to the tangent of $10$ degrees.

Comment: Thank you! Perfect explanation to what was going on, as you pointed out I was fundamentally incorrect on the setting of input variables ```(i,j,k)```. In my usage, these are actually set by a system I intend to interface with so I cannot modify them. I resolved to modify/read ```k``` as ```tan(arcsin(k))```. System now functions as intended!